# Google Chrome Instant blocks me from Google search

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I've been using chrome instant for a while on chrome PC, but I just enabled it on my Mac did 2 google searches and now I'm suspected of making automated requests.
 How can I use Google again, and why is it that ironically google chrome has got me blocked from google search, and I now have to use Bing?

(If google thinks I'm using their site too much with chrome instant, what hope have other websites got?)

Comment: I get something similar when I used the built in browser version of Google Instant, it would claim I polled their site too often, because it would update with every keypress... These are most likely bugs that will get fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much a Google issue. Google's automated spam detection can be.. a bit too strict at times.

I'd recommend you to take it up with Google, follow the link to the Help Center article and there's an option which states that request was not automated, that should get that ban off.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a bot, making a lot of google searches, on one or more of your computers on the LAN. It may not be a chrome issue.

If you are using a wireless router, make sure it is secure so that no one else can use it to run such a bot behind your network.

Google usually lifts the ban in a day or possibly in a couple of hours.

Comment: It is a bit of coincidence, its just as I used Google chrome instant for the first time on my mac. Also my other computer happens to be off at the moment, and using Bing I've seen others with a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems like quite the coincidence. I had a similar issue once and it was caused by a bot. I just wanted to share that with you just in case you had not looked into that possibility. Sorry, I have no further input on this one. Hope you find a solution.